# How to send data from a dialogue fragment to all fragments within a Viewpager?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-viewpager, fragment

I have run into the problem of sending data, a simple int type, from a dialogue fragment to all the fragments within a viewpager. I have an activity that hosts both the dialogue fragment and the viewpager. I know how to send data from the dialogue fragment to the activity using an interface defined in the dialogue fragment and implementing it within the activity itself. I was thinking maybe it had something to do with the onAttach method but i am not sure. i feel i am overlooking a simple solution here. please help! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared View Model containing a LiveData Object(holding your int). When you want to send data from the dialog fragment to the fragments in your view pager you can call the setValue method on the live data object and set up observers in each view pager fragment that are notified when the LiveData Object changes. If this is new to you then I recommend reading the Android Architecture components documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata
I hope that this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Learn " `setTargetFragment()` "

Where " `startActivityForResult()` " establishes a relationship between 2 activities, " `setTargetFragment()` " defines the caller/called relationship between 2 fragments.